# Pycharm cannot import math module

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I can't import standard math module in pycharm, I'm getting an error: "No module named math", from python shell I can import it, what can cause that?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more information on the code you use and how you have setup PyCharm

Comment: Updating PyCharm solved it for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you are pointing to the correct python file within Settings > Project > Project Interpreter.

When I've had this problem in the past my interpreter was pointing at *python3.6* and not *python* within the bin folder of my venv. I simply dropped the interpreter and added it again pointing to the venv-name/bin/python

Answer (score 1):

File >> Settings >> Project interpreter. You should see a list of currently installed packages/libraries. If the module is not specified in there click the plus sign and look for your module in there. Also make sure you specify it correctly when you import it.

Comment: I don't see math here, and I cannot install it from here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to fix it by creating a new Python system interpreter. `Project Interpreter` -> `Add Local` -> `System Interpreter` -> `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Answer (score 0):

import math -> instead of using "print(sqrt(25))" use "print(math.sqrt(25))" (here sqrt is for exp. only)

Comment: Please note the question says "I *can't import* the standard math module".