# I have install a new library by python, but i can't find in pythoncharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I have install a new library by python, `mpl_finance` successfully.

But I am unable to find the same in `Pycharm`.
what can i do ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm cannot import math module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893461/pycharm-cannot-import-math-module)

Comment: For one thing, your first screenshot appears to show "mp1-finance" being installed and your second screenshot shows you searching for "mpl_". What exact command did you run which produced the output seen in your first screenshot?

Comment: it is suppose mpl_finace 
because i am installing that https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance

Comment: python setup.py install

Comment: The question "[Candlestick OCHL graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42373104/8309965)" has a poor title (I've submitted a pending edit to fix it) but appears to be at least related to, and possibly be the same as, your issue. Please try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000950/8309965) and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Edit no longer pending, name of possible duplicate is now "[Since matplotlib.finance has been deprecated, how can I use the new mpl_finance module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42373104/8309965)"

Comment: actually, i have tired above solutions, but these methods not work for me . therefore i have degrade my vision to  matplotilb 2.1.5  which can use .finance directly.